# Changing Legend Items ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, legend-properties

I am trying to create a chart, but I can't change the names of the legend items. My database is in Spanish, and I need the legend items to appear in English. [Legend Items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HjC6R.png). Instead of "70 o más" I need "70+". I have already tried changing the value labels in the database and it is not working either.

This is the code for trying to change the value labels in the database

```
library(expss)

describe(Flow)


Flow = apply_labels(Flow,
                      mes = "Month",
                      ano= "Year", 
                      edad="Age", 
                    edad=c("70 or more" = "70 o Más S/E"),
```

This is the code for the chart:

```
    chart<-ggplot()+
  geom_line(data=Flow %>%
            aes(x=date,
                color=edad), stat="count") +
  scale_x_date(date_minor_breaks = "1 month",
               date_labels = "%Y (%b)") +
  labs(color="Age")+
ggtitle("Number of Entrances, 2017-2021") 
ggplotly(chart)
```

I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: If you provide some of your data, then I can refine my answer with your code. You can just edit your question here, and paste the results of `dput(Flow)`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `scale_colour_gradient` to set `breaks`, then change the `labels`.

```
library(tidyverse)

ggplot() +
  geom_line(data=mtcars,
              aes(x=cyl, y = mpg,
                  color=mpg)) +
  scale_colour_gradient(breaks = c(15, 20, 25, 30, 40),
                        labels = c("1+", "2+", "3+", "4+", "5+"))
```

Output

[image]